# Return the current section type? (plugin)

Tags: plugin-development, sections

Is there an easy way to check what the current page **section type** is, within a plugin?

I wonder if I'm overlooking a little function that simply returns: "single", "channel", "entry", etc...?

---

UPDATE:

Thank you Aevlan, this was the approach I took originally. I've been struggling to determine wether the user is currently on the root of a channel/structure, or if they are on an entry page.

This is how I can determine "single", "channel" or "structure".

```
$element = craft()->urlManager->getMatchedElement();
$element_exists = $element && $element->getElementType() == ElementType::Entry;

$currentPageType = $element->section->type;
```

The reason I need to know this, is so I can perform some checks before I add certain navigation throughout the site. To help with my specific issue, I will use "hasDescendants()" or check the segment counts.

Thanks again. Mark

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SectionModel has a type property, which return what you're after, "single", "channel" and "entry". In a template it can be accessed like this:

```
{{ entry.section.type }}
```

If this is in a plugin and you have the section, you access it like this:

```
$section->type
```

But I'm confused by the "current page" of your question. Maybe you can describe in a bit more detail what you're trying to achieve, and what your code looks like atm?